# Destructuring a struct containing a borrow in a function argument

Tags: struct, rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a system that would use borrow checking/lifetimes in order to provide safe custom indices on a collection. Consider the following code:

```
struct Graph(i32);

struct Edge<'a>(&'a Graph, i32);

impl Graph {
    pub fn get_edge(&self) -> Edge {
        Edge(&self, 0)
    }

    pub fn split(&mut self, Edge(_, edge_id): Edge) {
        self.0 = self.0 + edge_id;
    }

    pub fn join(&mut self, Edge(_, edge0_id): Edge, Edge(_, edge1_id): Edge) {
        self.0 = self.0 + edge0_id + edge1_id;
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph(0);
    let edge = graph.get_edge();
    graph.split(edge)
}
```

References to the graph borrowed by the `Edge` struct should be dropped when methods such as `split` or `join` are called. This would fulfill the API invariant that all edge indices must be destroyed when the graph is mutated. However, the compiler doesn't get it. It fails with messages like

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `graph` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:23:5
   |
22 |     let edge = graph.get_edge();
   |                ----- immutable borrow occurs here
23 |     graph.split(edge)
   |     ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
24 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

If I understand this correctly, the compiler fails to realise that the borrowing of the graph that happened in the edge struct is actually being released when the function is called. Is there a way to teach the compiler what I am trying to do here?

Bonus question: is there a way to do exactly the same but without actually borrowing the graph in the `Edge` struct? The edge struct is only used as a temporary for the purpose of traversal and will *never* be part of an external object state (I have 'weak' versions of the edge for that).

**Addendum**: After some digging around, it seems to be really far from trivial. First of all, `Edge(_, edge_id)` does not actually destructure the `Edge`, because `_` does not get bound at all (yes, `i32` is Copy which makes things even more complicated, but this is easily remedied by wrapping it into a non-Copy struct). Second, even if I completely destructure `Edge` (i.e. by doing it in a separate scope), the reference to the graph is still there, even though it should have been moved (this must be a bug). It only works if I perform the destructuring in a separate function. Now, I have an idea how to circumvent it (by having a separate object that describes a state change and destructures the indices as they are supplied), but this becomes very awkward very quickly.

Comment: This is a follow up question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852283/safe-non-trivial-data-dependencies-custom-references and is inspired by the answers I received there. Still, I decided that the new question is sufficiently different.

Comment: Because your `get_edge()` function returns an immutable reference of itself via `&self`, the immutable borrow will exist for as long as `edge1` exists. The borrow checker is thus working as intended. I'm not really sure why you're trying to return a reference to itself when all you want is the edge ID.

Comment: @mmstick Because edge ID potentially becomes invalid when the graph is mutated. I want to make sure that no instance of `Edge` for a graph can outlive a graph mutation. Note: I would actually use PhantomData<&Graph> here, but this doesn't change the question.

Comment: I think you might be running into the [Limits of lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html)

Comment: @WesleyWiser, thanks for the link. Yes, it seems like its the same problem. For my understanding: so lifetimes in Rust are really just labels for lexical scope rather then actual existence? E.g. if I destructure a struct by moving its fields out, it still is considered to be alive?

Comment: @MrMobster I would say in general yes lifetimes are labels for lexical scopes. There is a strong desire in the Rust community for "non-lexical lifetimes" see these for more info on that: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811 http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

You have a second problem that you didn’t mention: how does `split` know that the user didn’t pass an `Edge` from a different `Graph`?  Fortunately, it’s possible to solve both problems with higher-rank trait bounds!

First, let’s have `Edge` carry a `PhantomData` marker instead of a real reference to the graph:

```rust
pub struct Edge<'a>(PhantomData<&'a mut &'a ()>, i32);
```

Second, let’s move all the `Graph` operations into a new `GraphView` object that gets *consumed* by operations that should invalidate the identifiers:

```rust
pub struct GraphView<'a> {
    graph: &'a mut Graph,
    marker: PhantomData<&'a mut &'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> GraphView<'a> {
    pub fn get_edge(&self) -> Edge<'a> {
        Edge(PhantomData, 0)
    }

    pub fn split(self, Edge(_, edge_id): Edge) {
        self.graph.0 = self.graph.0 + edge_id;
    }

    pub fn join(self, Edge(_, edge0_id): Edge, Edge(_, edge1_id): Edge) {
        self.graph.0 = self.graph.0 + edge0_id + edge1_id;
    }
}
```

Now all we have to do is guard the construction of `GraphView` objects such that there’s never more than one with a given lifetime parameter `'a`.

We can do this by (1) forcing `GraphView<'a>` to be [invariant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) over `'a` with a `PhantomData` member as above, and (2) only ever providing a constructed `GraphView` to a closure with a higher-rank trait bound that creates a fresh lifetime each time:

```rust
impl Graph {
    pub fn with_view<Ret>(&mut self, f: impl for<'a> FnOnce(GraphView<'a>) -> Ret) -> Ret {
        f(GraphView {
            graph: self,
            marker: PhantomData,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph(0);
    graph.with_view(|view| {
        let edge = view.get_edge();
        view.split(edge);
    });
}
```

[Full demo on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cc50cc248b6db1deb4910a5bdd3cfa19).

This isn’t totally ideal, since the caller may have to go through contortions to put all its operations inside the closure.  But I think it’s the best we can do in the current Rust language, and it does allow us to enforce a huge class of compile-time guarantees that almost no other language can express at all.  I’d love to see more ergonomic support for this pattern added to the language somehow—perhaps a way to create a fresh lifetime via a return value rather than a closure parameter (`pub fn view(&mut self) -> exists<'a> GraphView<'a>`)?

Comment: *it’s possible to solve both problems with higher-rank trait bounds* — An admirable attempt, but [it doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35a61cfd84008841ec868830eb8c4731). Lifetimes have subtyping relationships.

Comment: @Shepmaster My mistake, I forgot to force `GraphView` to be invariant. This version should be secure against that attack.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! I still need to wrap my head around some details (like the `&'a mut &'a` notation), but I will see whether this can work for my purpose.  It would be nice if the system offered more clear ways to model such invariants. I'd like to see some sort of abstract state modelling + local instance-dependent types. Rust lifetimes are great, but in their current form probably not sufficient...

Comment: *forcing `GraphView<'a>` to be invariant over `'a`* — You used `PhantomData<&'a mut &'a ()>`, but the page you linked to says that `PhantomData<Cell<&'a ()>>` is needed for lifetime invariance. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: @Shepmaster There’s no discrepancy; there are infinitely many types that are invariant over `'a`, of which one example is `Cell<&'a ()>` (see the `Cell<T>` entry in the table on the page I linked), and another example is `&'a mut &'a ()` (see the `&'a mut T` entry in the same table). I just arbitrarily picked one that I didn’t have to import anything for.